# UPDATE query to synchronize duplicated records

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of duplicate records in a table, highly simplfied example is:

```
name, emailaddress, importantid
John Smith, john@smith.com, NULL
John Smith, john@smith.com, 12345
John Smith, john@smith.com, NULL
```

The problem comes later when another table is joined to this, it may be joined to one of the records which doesn't have the importantid I need.

I'm looking to update the table so that for each email address it finds the first one where importantid is not null and then updates the other records with that id, so all duplicate accounts end up having the important id.

How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/PHTGYA62309)**

```
UPDATE a
SET a.importantid = b.importantid
FROM test AS a
JOIN (SELECT emailaddress, max(importantid) as importantid
      FROM test 
      GROUP BY emailaddress) AS b
ON a.emailaddress = b.emailaddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET importanid =(SELECT max(importantid)
             FROM yourTable t2
             WHERE t2.emailaddress = t1.emailaddress AND t1.importantid is null and t2.importantid is not null)
```